# trying to get name of enclosing class in a Rails concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

First time using concerns and just looking for some advice.

I have a Rails model called location.rb and would like to include an AlbumDefineConcern and then query which model class we are currently in (in this class Location).

I have:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AlbumDefineConcern
  ...
```

and

```
module AlbumDefineConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  albums={}
  albums_locations = ["LocationHomeFeed","LocationProfile","LocationMobileMain"]
  albums[:locations]=albums_locations
  # I'd like it to output location or Location
  puts "here is class_name #{self.name}"
```

How would I get "location" as the class name?

```
#  puts "here is class_name #{self.parent.name}" => Object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module AlbumDefineConcern
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        puts self
    end

end
```